# How to check if a vector contains numbers in R with Stringr?

Tags: r, regex, vector, stringr

Working with R language. It says unexpected token of brackets and parenthesis. The pattern seems like it would work too. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if (str_detect(c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602"), [0-9])) {
    print("Oh no!")
} else {
    print("Yay!")
}
```

ANSWER: "No quotations around regex"
HOWEVER: it only checks for the first element. **How do I check for all of the elements in vector?**

Comment: Check your use of quotation marks...?

Comment: You need to put quotes around the regex, like `"[0-9]"`. And there's no actual need for `if/else`, just run `str_detect(c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602"), "[0-9]")` and let R's vectorised operations work.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you. But now, I am running into the problem where it only checks the first element. How do i make it so that it checks every element in the vector?

Comment: Like I said, remove the whole `if/else` check. `str_detect(c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602"), "[0-9]")` on its own will give the correct results.

Comment: I need it to return the "oh no" and "yay." How would I include that?

Comment: hasDigits <- str_detect(c("INFO 201", "CSE 142"), "[0-9]")
if (hasDigits) {
  print("Oh no!")
} else {
  print("Yay!")
}

This also just checks the first element only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check for the presence of at least one number in the string, then you may try using this:

```
str_detect(c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602"), ".*[0-9].*")
```

or possibly this as well:

```
str_detect(c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602"), "(?=.*[0-9]).*")
```

If you need to check each word separately if it contains a number then try this:

```
input <- c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602")
output <- sapply(input, function(x) {
    words <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+"))
    num_matches <- sapply(words, function(y) str_detect(y, ".*[0-9].*"))
    result <- length(words) == sum(num_matches)
    return(result)
})

if (sum(output) == 0) {
    print("Yay!")
}
else {
    print("Oh no!")
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That works as well.

Comment: But, I need the "yay" and "oh no" if/else part to work with all of the elements of the vector. It only works for the first element of the vector. How would I fix that?

Comment: @R.Kim Are you saying that every word in the string needs to contain a number?  Or something else?

Comment: the "if/else" statements should go thru each element of the vector (such as the "Hello 241" and the "whawt 602"). Right now, it only checks the first - "hello 241"

Comment: @R.Kim I updated my answer.

Comment: ok so it returns: FALSE FALSE. How would i then say: if the results are all false, then return "yes".

Comment: @R.Kim Yes, because each term contains one word which does not have numbers in it.  Do you expect TRUE TRUE?  In other words, are you looking for the presence of just a single word containing a number?

Comment: ok so it returns: FALSE FALSE. How would i then say: if the results are all false, then return "yay"

Comment: Just take the sum of that vector.  True and false cast to 1 and 0, respectively, so if the sum is zero, then it means that everything was false.

Comment: What would that look like in code? Thank you so much btw.

Comment: I updated my answer already with that code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
ifelse(grepl( '[0-9]', c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602",'Nope')),'Oh no!','Yay!')
```

If you want to check for all elements at once, just wrap `all()` around the `grepl`:

```
ifelse(all(grepl( '[0-9]', c("Hello 241", "Whawt 602",'Nope'))),'Oh no!','Yay!')
```